# jQuery plugin: table with CRUD

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Any recommendations for a jQuery table plugin that will allow me to add, edit, and delete rows (would tie in to DB records)? Flexgrid doesn't have edit capability. Scrolling, sorting, and pagination might be useful features too.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQGrid - http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Or wait until the official release of a grid comes from JQueryUI (in the works at the moment, http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid )

Answer (score 0):

you might try http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php which seems to be quite neat (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

I used Kendo UI WEB Open Source (http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx)
Also you can try using JTable http://www.jtable.org/

Answer (score 0):

From non-commercial solutions, it is also good to look at the [jTable](http://www.jtable.org) plugin for jQuery, which has features requested and is under MIT license.