# Javascript, HTML and CSS Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, grid

I am ASP.NET MVC to develop my application on web. This app requires a grid to display, sort, and modify the data. User can perform all crud operation using this grid and needs to hide any column as per need. I have searched a lot on internet to find any free HTML based control which fulfill this requirement but I did not find.

I just want to have a grid which fulfill the above requirement either that only based on java script or it have some dependencies on ASP.NET MVC frame work like other grids which are based on server side scripting which generates HTML on run time.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that may help:

[Ext Js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2) - Javascript solution... maybe a little overkill, but tons of stuff out of the box.

[Tutorial](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2011/09/25/using-crud-operations-with-jquery-iggrid-entity-framework-and-and-asp-net-mvc3.aspx) - Using CRUD Operations with jQuery igGrid, Entity Framework and ASP.Net MVC3

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239187/jquery-plugin-table-with-crud) - Some more javascript solutions here.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx).

Comment: I have used Telerik grid before but I want a free control.

Comment: @user86, there's a free license for GPLv2 projects: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/download.aspx